# htaccess rewrite - not rewriting to index.php 2

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^Interface/Base/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2findex.html.var$ Interface/Base/Login.aspx [R,NC,L]
```

is not working. I want it to redirect to Login.aspx so it can work this is mapping another site by doing

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8880/$1 [P,L]
```

Rewrite file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Interface/Base/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2findex.html.var$ Interface/Base/Login.aspx [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8880/$1 [P,L]
```

IP is hidden for protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match query string in `RewriteRule` use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ReturnUrl=.*?index\.html\.var$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Interface/Base/Login\.aspx$ /Interface/Base/Login.aspx? [R,NC,L]
```